# Set "Configure Search Navigation" in search setting in SharePoint Online using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-search

[image]

I want to mark checkbox to **true** for **use the same search navigation links as my parent** using PowerShell script as I have 100+ Subsites. I tries to some scripts but they did not work so it would be great if you can help me on this.
Thank you.

Output :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have found that some server-side solutions are not applicable to SharePoint Online. Maybe you can open a service request in your SharePoint Online admin center to get the exact information.
[image]